# Selenium how to click on a radio button when by.id does not work

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium and nodjs (v16) on an internal website strong text I have a radio button that needs to be clicked.  I have tried everything and I still cannot click it.  Any assitance would be appreciated.

I have tried

```
driver.findElement(By.id("chk14")).click()
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//INPUT[@ID=\"chk14\"]")).click()
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='chk14']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='chk14' and @name='I1']")).click();
```

None work.

Here is the code line with * is one with radio button.

```
<table id="aatbl14" class="JJJMCOptionTable" itemseq="1" keyseq="4" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><div role="document"><table id="itmstem1" class="YTGStem" itemseq="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="YTGStemSequence" valign="top">1.&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td class="YTGStemText" valign="top"><p><span class="QNumber">R.</span> What number comes before 35 and after 20?</p></td>
</tr></tbody></table></div><tbody><tr id="frtr14">
*<td class="YTGMCOptionMarkerCell" valign="top"><input id="chk14" class="YTGMCOptionMarker" type="radio" aria-labelledby="iqdacc14" name="I1" value="4" seq="4" itemseq="1"></td>*
<td class="YTGMCOptionLabelTextCell" valign="top"><div id="item14" class="YTGMCOptionLabelText"><label for="chk14"></label></div></td>
<td class="YTGMCOptionLabelSeparatorCell" valign="top"><div id="sep14" class="YTGMCOptionLabelSeparator"><label for="chk14"></label></div></td>
<td class="YTGMCOptionTextCell" id="oltc14" valign="top"><label id="iqdacc14" for="chk14" class="YTGMCOptionACCLabel"><div id="radio14" class="YTGMCOptionText" strikeout="1,4"><p>29</p></div></label>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Is the input visible when you try to click it? Are there any errors when clicking?

Comment: Did you try with javascript click function?

Comment: Input is visable.  there is a 20 second delay to allow the iframe to load.   AbiSaran: what do you mean by the javascript click function?

Comment: @user3689158 AbiSaran means this `driver.executeScript("argument[0].click()", element)` where `element` is for example `element = driver.findElement(By.id("chk14"))`

Comment: what is the error msg in the console?

Comment: if show error - no_such_element -> then you need to load that page properly before click, if error - element_not_visible -> then you need to scroll to that element before click

Comment: No errors.   It just doesn't do anything.  Nothing is checked.  I did a loop where I tried to check it 100 times.  No error, just nothing checked.   As regards driver.executeScript, we are running Javascript already.   Its not a page load issue, we delay 20 seconds.  If we don't delay, we get no_such_element or element not traceable.

Answer (score 0):

It turns the problem was that the page was not fully loading when the click was executed. Once a delay was introducted it worked.

Comment: why answer your own question? :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).